# Finding memory leaks in a C++ application with VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-code, memory-leaks, vscode-debugger

Is there a way to show memory leaks report in a C++ application using Visual Studio Code?

Perhaps a certain library? An extension? Using MinGW compiler?

I'm using Visual Studio Code (1.41.1) on Windows 10 with C++ extension (0.26.3).
I've configured VS Code with MSVC compiler toolset (2019) as written in [Configure VS Code for Microsoft C++](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc).
However I'm unable to show memory leaks using the CRT library, as written in [Find memory leaks with the CRT library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/finding-memory-leaks-using-the-crt-library?view=vs-2019).
My simple example code:

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    printf("Hello world!\n");

    int *a = new int;
    *a = 8;
    //delete a;

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}
```

Using this code I cannot see any report generated by `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()`.
When debugging the code it seems that the compiler skips the line `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();` entirely.
Am I doing something wrong?
I've tried changing the configurations with `_DEBUG=1` define, however the compiler even skips a `#ifdef _DEBUG` statement.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you can find memory leaks in VS Code C++ application with MSVC by simply adding the compiler option `"/MDd"` or `"/MTd"` in the `args` array of the `tasks.json` file within the project's `.vscode` folder (without any 3rd party application or tool).
Something like this:

```
"args": [
            "/Zi", // Generates complete debugging information
            "/MDd", // Use /MDd or /MTd to define _DEBUG and allow _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()
            "/EHsc", // Specifies the model of exception handling - mode 'sc'
            "/Fe:", // Renames the executable file
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "${file}"
        ],
```

This basically enables everything listed in [Find memory leaks with the CRT library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/finding-memory-leaks-using-the-crt-library?view=vs-2019)
Then, when running the program, `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` detects the memory leaks and shows them within the `DEBUG CONSOLE`:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{113} normal block at 0x015C8460, 4 bytes long.
 Data: <    > 08 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

Finally, you can enter the number within the curly brackets into the `_CrtSetBreakAlloc(113)` command to create a memory-allocation breakpoint to find which variable you forgot to delete.

Comment: this was working for me a few days ago.  Today I come back and the program is just skipping over that call to  _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks  any idea why?